# Best method to use carpet samples squares to create a Rug?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, underlayment, diy-vs-pro

I have plenty of carpet samples and I wanted to make an area rug with them.

I would like to make a rug out of them,  maybe I can create a pattern with the carpet squares and then glue them to some kind of soft padding/underlay.

I was thinking to use carpet underlay and glue the samples to it directly. I am not sure if that's possible, and  in the case that it is possible, **what kind of glue** can be purchased in order to stick the two surfaces together? (*considering that each piece of carpet has a different backing*).

What kind of underlay should I consider to use?

Any advise will be really appreciated :)
*I am trying to do this without breaking the bank.*

[image]

Photo added to illustrate the project.

Comment: There is carpet tape designed to join carpet together - which is very strong.

Comment: carpet foam would quickly fall apart, it's not meant to handle sheer.

Comment: I disagree that this is an arts and crafts based question. Why is building a rug for your home not DIY home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

One method, like in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HWCf_P4wlE), would be to use  heat bond carpet seaming tape.  Pro carpet installers use it with a special iron to seam carpet together, but you can use a clothes iron since you will be working on the back side. This would give a strong bond but you will still need a rug pad to keep it from sliding around. (*The heat seal tape has a paper backing that is not removable and will be slippery on smooth flooring*)

You could use [double sided carpet tape](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Shurtape-1-88-in-x-75-ft-White-Double-sided-Seam-Tape/3407976) in conjunction with a cheap [non-slip rug pad](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Style-Selections-8-FT-x-10-FT-Premium-Rug-Pad-2/1002550446). (*or not so cheap alternative* [Pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T6RQGSI))

Lay out your samples in the pattern you want, then flip each over so the back side it up. Use the tape to tape all of the seams and put a border of tape all around the perimeter. Place the tape just in from the outside of the outer borders, about   a 1/4 inch in. Put two tape strips across, perpendicular, to each seam for added strength in holding them together.

When dispensing and cutting your tape, leave the protective backing on and put the sticky side down, then press all of the tape down firmly. (*Use a rolling pin or a can of tomatoes as a roller to help press it down*.)

Unfold the rug pad and then roll it up like a big roll of carpet and place it on one end of the taped together samples so that it will roll out and over the samples as you unroll it. (*You can trim it down to just bigger then your rug you are making, Dont worry about cutting it exactly to fit, you can do that after it is taped in place.*) Position it and roll it out over the rug to make sure it cover the whole rug with little hanging over all four sides then roll it back being careful not to move it side to side.

Now peel of the protective backing on ALL of the tape and start to unroll the pad onto the Taped rug. Use your roller to  press all of the seams and edges.

Now you can trim the pad just inside the outer border, That is why we left that 1/4 inch gap. You can use small scissors or carefully cut with a utility knife so the pad is not visible.

Comment: Great answer, except I think I might use a different material for the backing -- the one you linked has holes in it, which could allow the adhesive in the tape to either stick to the floor, or pick up a lot of dust and get gross quickly.   A better option might be a sheet of rubber such as is used in commercial rugs.

Comment: @NateS. When one "sweeps it under the rug", one wants it to stay there :)- I edited in a more expensive alternative.